# I cant set/use the function of MyLocationOverlay?

Tags: android, openstreetmap

Is there an another Import ?

```
  import org.andnav.osm.views.overlay.MyLocationOverlay;
```

I use the given one and got the error The constructor `MyLocationOverlay(MainActivity, MapView)` is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please have a look at

https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/source/browse/trunk/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/org/andnav/osm/views/overlay/MyLocationOverlay.java?r=119

it i clear that the constructor is as follows

```
MyLocationOverlay(final Context ctx, final OpenStreetMapView mapView)
```

means you need to pass the context and also the mapView which is of type `OpenStreetMapView`  so please take care of these two things, it will solve yours problem.

for the use please have a look at

**https://github.com/royiby/OSMap**

beside this the jar is available at http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadosmdroidandroid104jar.htm

Comment: the osmdroid 1.04 is all Ready imported to the Project.And i want use (MapView mapview) and don't OpenstreetMapview mapView or did I missunderstood something

Comment: as you said you do not want's to use OpenstreetMapview  you need to work on this part else it will not work!! you can make a similar custom class as OpenstreetMapview  which can have properties of MapView.